# How to generate a list of which Features are enabled in which Spaces?

Tags: views, 6, organic-groups, features

I'm running a Drupal 6.x site with Organic Groups, Features, and Spaces, and I'm interested in generating a list of which Spaces have which Features enabled. Preferably a table, with Spaces along the Y axis, and Features along the X axis.

Any ideas regarding how to generate this? I can generate a list of Group Spaces using Views, but can't find a field for the enabled Features.

Answer (score 2):

Features are modules, and Views 3.x can make listings of enabled modules. But as explained in [How to make a Feature available only to certain Spaces?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272), this is not possible, since modules are enabled site-wide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a field to be able to do this with a view. Mainly because the data is stored in a serialized object.

But the query you want to use would be something like this.

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM {spaces_overrides} WHERE object_type = 'variable' and object_id = 'spaces_features'");
```

Once you get those results the features for that specific space is going to be in the value column. Is going to be a serialized array so you will have to unserialized it.

The value is going to be a key => value array of feature_name => status.

Sadly you're going to have to build the page and the table yourself. But this should be enough to get the data that you want.

Also you're going to have do a lookup for the for the ID to get the proper group name.

Sorry the solutions is not as simple but this should work.