# How to make a Feature available only to certain Spaces?

Tags: 6, organic-groups, features

For a Drupal 6 Open Atrium site (i.e., Features, Spaces, Organic Groups) I'm running, I've created some custom Features that only really apply to a handful of the hundreds of groups on the site.

As it stands, the "Customize Features" config screen shows *all* the Features, including those I'd like to intentionally restrict to just a couple of special groups.

What's the best way to prevent these special Features from being offered to every group, while retaining those Features on the special groups?

Comment: Could you enable all of the features from the start, but handle their display via [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context)? I haven't had a chance to try Context myself yet, but it sounds like a fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features for each space are configured via the `spaces_features_form()` function. You could implement [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to selectively and conditionally remove features from specific groups.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'spaces_features_form') {
    $space = spaces_get_space();
    // Populate the array with hard-coded NIDs, or whatever logic
    // needed to determine if these features should be allowed.
    if ($space->type == 'og' && !in_array($space->group->nid, array(...))) {
      // Hide features foo and bar.
      foreach (array('feature_foo', 'feature_bar') as $feature) {
        $form['spaces_features'][$feature]['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Features are modules. Modules are enabled system-wide and cannot be linked to a Space or Group. However, you could control access to them by creating custom permissions, see [hook_perm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_perm/6).

Comment: This isn't quite true. Features can be selectively enabled on a per-space basis, but you're right in that they can't automatically be hidden from the spaces features configuration form.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add to this hook_perm suggestion an alteration on the form to disable the applicable feature based on the group type. hook_form_alter probably wont work cause the feature related items won't be present yet. You may have to register an [#after_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#after_build) hook and then modify the form accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Context is definitely the way to go.
[Context](http://drupal.org/project/context), [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) and [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces) are a powerful combination. This DevelopmentSeed post should help: [Building a "Blog Feature" in Drupal with Context and Spaces](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/jan/30/easy-feature-building-spaces)